# What if someone new wants to comment on a question?

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges

I'm pretty new to Stack Overflow and it's vote-system, but I've notice a problem for new users.

I don't know if it's by design or a bug or what else.

For example:

- someone posts an unclear question.
- I may know the answer, but I'm not sure of the question and I want to ask "questioner" more information about his/her problem BUT I can't comment on his/her question because I haven't that privilege yet.

What can I do?

Comment: This is by design, see for example [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114534/why-does-stack-overflow-prevent-new-users-from-commenting) for some reasons why that "barrier" exists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Move on to another question that you are sure of.  You can always click the star to "favorite" the question so you can come back to it once you've gained the 50 reputation needed to comment everywhere.

(Please **do not** post clarifying questions using the Answer text box.  Moderators have to clean up several dozen (hundreds?) of these every day.)